# Can I merge discriminated unions and records using a value on a property in the DU

Tags: typescript

given the following types

```
type MyDU =
    | {kind: 'foo'}
    | {kind: 'bar'}
    | {kind: 'baz'}

type MyRec1 = {
    foo: string
    bar: number
}

type MyRec2 = {
    bar: number
    baz: boolean
}
```

I'd like to have a mapped/conditional type

```
type DURecMerger<D, R> = ...
```

such that

```
type X = DURecMerger<MyDU, MyRec1>
type Y = DURecMerger<MyDU, MyRec2>
```

produces the following result

```
type X =
    | {kind: 'foo', foo: string}
    | {kind: 'bar', bar: number}
    | {kind: 'baz'}

type Y =
    | {kind: 'foo'}
    | {kind: 'bar', bar: number}
    | {kind: 'baz', baz: boolean}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `D` type is already a discriminated union where all elements of the union contain exactly one common property key whose value are distinct key-like literals, you can write `DURecMerger` like this:

```
type DURecMerger<
    D extends Record<keyof D, PropertyKey>,
    R extends Partial<Record<D[keyof D], any>>
    > = {
        [K in D[keyof D]]: (
            Extract<D, Record<keyof D, K>> & (K extends keyof R ? Pick<R, K> : unknown)
        ) extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never
    }[D[keyof D]];
```

The type `keyof D` will turn out to be the single key common to all elements in the `D` union, so `D[keyof D]` will be the union of all of the discriminant values.  It is `D[keyof D]` that we then iterate over as `K` in a mapped type and synthesize our members.

First we `Extract<D, Record<keyof D, K>>`, meaning we get the element of `D` corresponding to the disciminant of `K`.  And then we check to see if `K` is a key in `R`.  If so, we `Pick<R, K>` and intersect it with the value we're building up.  Otherwise we leave it alone.

The construct `(...) extends infer O ? {[P in keyof O]: O[P]} : never` is a trick to make sure that the underlying intersection type gets expanded into a single object type.  So the type `{kind: "foo"} & {foo: string}` will become `{kind: "foo"; foo: string}`.

And finally we take the values of this mapped type and return it.

You can verify that it acts as expected on your examples:

```
type X = DURecMerger<MyDU, MyRec1>;
/* type X = {
    kind: 'foo';
    foo: string;
} | {
    kind: 'bar';
    bar: number;
} | {
    kind: 'baz';
} */
```

and

```
type Y = DURecMerger<MyDU, MyRec2>
/* type Y = {
    kind: 'foo';
} | {
    kind: 'bar';
    bar: number;
} | {
    kind: 'baz';
    baz: boolean;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiBVKBeAUFTUA+UDeUA1gJYB2AJgFxQDkAZgPYM1QC+GWuBJF1NARgEMATi3ZYc+ImSq0hALzFo0oSLBAAlCAGMAjKnwdMjBtQDOwYWQDmRqEOHVSAVwC2-CMLTsV4aHC1tACYDPDsHJzcPLwkFan4mABsIQVJvZVVoJECYT2tPAB47eCgIAA9gCAozKECGYXICwggQBjooeAAaKAAFYQZIYVAAaRaAPk67DVKKqvIanpFgYkFEgrqGgvgAbWbW9vgAXW7UkDGxuzHQuwlt4agyDt2Wto7Dw+oAChuJLABRCrCQTaYBbbobRp7V5dKDDc5QABkUE+93KlWqRBe7WmAH5esRtIR1t04VBqM5SIRSAwAO6kACUP0w9Jm6PmD1IdE8UAA8lA8QRtj0OZj9ryPryhYc2GSoKQIAA3Tx2VjbHZQg7vADcGF8agAGgZsjpcsJ8sICnAkN0AjpdGMdQB6ABUUEyUENKEMEh4snoTBoOokJnMlhsOtYkjCPpkfAcgfCIki7k8Eajdl9ccEijTzsdeugAE0jYgcnlClbEDbNDoghcXW6-FBi17o1hM7QTAnI1wM7G5CIE7Ek3KoqnvOmY7wBznE-J4kkUqRc-mgA)